# VBA Lookup value, return all unique values associated with the lookup value (in userform textbox)

Tags: vba, excel, userform

What I am trying to do is use VBA to get around Vlookup's limitations, and create a Userform that will display relevant items for a customer number.  I have a column full of duplicate values (customer numbers), then the column next to it has unique values (customer events).  Here's a short chunk of my table:

```
CustNum      CustEvent
123          Called In
123          Placed Order
345          Filed Complaint
345          Called In
345          Refund Approved
```

I created a userform that allows our employees to search through column A, and it returns what is in column B.  I did this with a vLookup, but everyone knows vLookup's limitations, as it will only return the first value in B that it runs into.

What I need is for my UserForm textbox to display the top five customer event hits:

```
Search: 123

Called In, Placed Order
```

Eventually this will be run through SQL tables that I don't have write access to, so changing the data is not an option.

My code:

```
Dim x As Long

x = cnum.Value

textbox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Range("A2:B5"), 2, False)
```

Comment: Why not just run a separate `select distinct` query against the table?

Comment: You can use an advanced filter to do this.

Comment: I am still very new to the SQL side of things.  Do you have a link or example to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VBA function to get this sorted. I have written the function, can be made more robust; but this should give you the basic idea.

[image]

The code behind this is a simple function that will take the ID as its argument and then return all related records. Idea based on Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated method](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

```
Public Function ConcatRelated(InputID As Long) As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, iCtr As Long, retStr As String

    lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For iCtr = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(iCtr, 1).Value = InputID Then
            retStr = retStr & Cells(iCtr, 2).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next

    If Len(retStr) > 0 Then _
        retStr = Left(retStr, Len(retStr) - 2)

    ConcatRelated = retStr
End Function
```

I hope this will be of some help ! Good luck.